# Ho do know that document.createElement('img') will be completed sync?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I'm trying to understand async/await and stuck with problem in example.

I know that if i have 2 functions like:

```
f1(//console.log(1) after 5 sec)
f2(//console.log(2) after 1 sec)
```

result will be:

```
2
1
```

Ok, now we have async function official example

```
async function showAvatar() {
      // read our JSON
      let response = await fetch('/article/promise-chaining/user.json');
      let user = await response.json();

      // show the avatar
      let img = document.createElement('img'); //but why they sure it will completed sync and not async and document.body.append will not append not yet existing img?
      document.body.append(img);
    }

    showAvatar();
```

But document.createElement('img') is function too like f1, it can lag, but for some reason we are not using await on it?
Why is it?

Comment: Creating an element would never be async, so you can't really await it. It may take time but that would block the execution thread until it finishes.

Comment: `document.createElement('img')` does not *lag* ... it returns immediately with the created tag element ...

Comment: but it's a function just like f1, why it can't lag?

Comment: no, it's a function like `function createElement(type) { return element[type]; }` ... there is no asynchrony in creating an element, no matter what type of element it is

Comment: It isn't a function like `f1` because `f1` will delay to a later point in time.

Comment: even `f1` isn't a function like what you think `f1` is ... just because it `console.log` after 5 seconds, doesn't mean that any useful result is returned after 5 seconds ... a console.log returns undefined, so there's nothing special about waiting for 5 seconds before outputting to the console

Comment: @vlaz  i'am trying to understand why javascript will not jump to do next function not waiting for first to complete like in f1/f2 example. So if i understand you right rule is that if function insides return immediately - javascript will not jump to execute another one?

Comment: you have not shown f1 or f2 ... so your question is meaningless - what is the point of calling f1 and f2? what do they do? do they return some value? is the value returned immediately? as is, your question lacks any meaning

Comment: @Jaromanda X thay have simple setTimeout()

Comment: Because all operations in JS are synchronous, unless otherwise noted. If you have `a = 2+2` and on the next line `console.log(a)` JS would never try to print before evaluating `2+2` or assigning that value to `a`. It's how JS works. There are, however, async functions like `setTimeout` or AJAX calls that do finish early and do more logic outside the normal flow of the program (evaluating each line). `f1` uses `setTimeout` (I guess?) which is asynchronous. There is no reason to believe EVERY function would work the same, though.

Comment: if f1 and f2 just wait for some amount of time then output to console, then of course, the one that waits the shortest amount of time will output first - in your example, both f1 and f2 are called, executed and finished before either of them output to console ... they both add a task to the timeout queue, which gets called later

Comment: @RTWTMI - just because f1 and f2 call setTimeout doesn't mean they are *asynchronous* ... `setTimeout` is asynchronous ... that doesn't make f1 or f2 asynchronous, because they don't "communicate" back to whatever called them after the timeout

Comment: thanks everyone, i understand now!

Comment: watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0) to understand how javascript works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But document.createElement('img') is function too like f1, it can lag, but for some reason we are not using await on it? Why is it?

That is because [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) is a reserved keyword, to be used only within `async function`. Not outside it. The incentive of the `await` operator is to wait for a promise. So when you are doing

```
await foo();
```

then it works only if `foo()` returns a `Promise` object.

The following statement,

```
document.createElement('img');
```

does not return a Promise object but a `HTMLImageElement`. That is not a `Promise` object, so you cannot wait on it using `await`. There is an `onload` event that you can use to have an action that acts once an image is being loaded in:

```
const img = document.createElement('img');
img.onload = _ => console.log('after load');
img.src = 'url';
```

when the last statement is handled, the browser is retrieving information from the given url. When it is done with loading the information, it will call `.onload` to indicate that it is done with loading in the image data.

EDIT:

It is possible to run

```
async function loadImage() {
  const img = await document.createElement('img');
  ...
}
```

without error because `await` will convert the result to a resolved Promise if it is not a `Promise` object. The following quote is taken from MDN:

> If the value of the expression following the await operator is not a Promise, it's converted to a resolved Promise. [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

So, the returned `HTMLImageElement` is converted to a `Promise` object via a [`Promise.resolve(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) call. Then the `await` then handle the promise object as indicated.

Comment: 1)So my example can throw Error if i'm not using img.onload or other callback when creating of element is not dont, but i will try to use it? 
2)And that rule is the same for any function?

Comment: `it works only if foo() returns a Promise object.` - this is actually incorrect. You can (successfully) `await` on any function (as long as you are inside an `async` tagged function of course) ... it's just  pointless :p

Comment: not i'm confused. Why do you saying that document.createElement('img') will be completed sync in my example?

Comment: `document.createElement('img')` is synchronous ... there is no asynchrony in `document.createElement` at all ... the asyncrhonous part comes when waiting for the img to LOAD, and that only happens once you assign a value to it's `src` property

Comment: @RTWTMI updated the post to add clarification when you do `await document...`

Comment: @Jaromanda X but why f1() can be async and document.createElement() not?

Comment: @RTWTMI the `f1()` in your post is not complete. Does it have a `window.setTimeout` in it? If so, then it operates asynchronously.

Comment: you haven't shown what `f1` is, a function is considered asynchronous if a meaningful result is available at some indeterminate time in the future - createElement creates the element immediately, so it's not that it "can't be asynchronous" it just isn't

Comment: @KarelG - even so, if calling f1() results in some setTimeout, that doesn't really make the function asynchronous, unless after the timeout, the function wishes to "return" a result to the caller :p

Comment: @JaromandaX that is true. I should specify that the function (where the console is being logged) for `window.setTimeout` happens asynchronously. I cannot edit my comment anymore though. :X